# pretty url image using htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

i want to learn htaccess coding. I was succesfully pretty my url, but idk why my image url rule not work. After several try i still not solved it yet.

**my real url:**

http://localhost/project/osclass/oc-content/uploads/img-post/117/156.jpg

**what i want:**

http://localhost/project/osclass/oc-content/uploads/img-post/117/156-some-pretty-title-here.jpg

**htaccess**:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M

Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/osclass/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project/osclass/index.php [L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule project/osclass/oc-content/uploads/img-post/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)-(.*)+\.([a-z]+)$ project/osclass/oc-content/uploads/img-post/$1/$2.$4 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

**example**:
http://localhost/project/osclass/oc-content/uploads/img-post/117/156-asdasda-asdasd-asdasd.jpg >> not found

i tested my regex and it works, but why my htaccess not work?

regex: https://regexr.com/3niu5

did i miss my regex?

Comment: You are already rewriting _everything_ that is not an existing file or directory to `/project/osclass/index.php` in your first “block” ... Rule of thumb: Your more specific rewrites should always happen before the more generic ones.

Comment: your answer give me clue, i will try that. thanks man

Comment: @CBroe works now, thankss brooo